# Python program that allows a person to run a script only once in 24 hours

Tags: python

How can I make a python program that allows the user to run a script(or a function) only once in 24 hours?

Comment: Can you give more details? This is probably a job for `cron`

Comment: Like you don't want the user to run the script more than one time a day, or you want to schedule it to run once a day? If it is scheduling you can use cron jobs.

Comment: I don't want the user to run the script more than one time a day.

Comment: is it once in 24 hours or once in a day?

Comment: There are a python package called [python-crontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab) that allows you  to do the same that with `cron` but directly from Python.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to store the last day and hour of execution inside a file or database.

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write('DATE_HERE')
```

Once the script runs, you have to check the last date, and if it has not been 24h, then don't execute the function.

Like some people say in comments, if all you want is scheduling, you can use cronjobs.

Comment: This did not help!

Comment: @AdityaSingh: So what's your problem with this solution? Why can't you use an external file?

Comment: @AdityaSingh This solution is the most easiest way how you can do it...

Comment: Actually I was having a problem in converting date time object into string and vice versa for storing in text file. Now the task has been accomplished :) Thanks everyone!